# SSIS Package Deployment

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package and it was scheduled as job. I made changes in the package and try to re-deploy the package but at that time the scheduled job running. How it will effect ?

Comment: I dont think, there will be any impact on the running package. When we initiate an SSIS package through job, an instance of it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to understand how SQL Server Agent works internally or some sort of it's [logical architecture](http://www.yaldex.com/sql_server_tutorial_3/ch08lev1sec6.html). Any SQL server agent action is get translated into a series of stored procedure calls. Actions typically result in metadata changes inside the SQL Server store. If such a change requires an immediate update of SQL Server Agent's internal data cache or a direct response from SQL Server Agent, the extended stored procedure xp_sqlagent_notify is called to place a formatted message in a shared memory object from SQL Server. SQL Server Agent continuously looks at this communication channel and processes all information placed into the shared memory object sequentially.

[image]

SQL Server Agent is a Windows service, so if your deployment was successful then agent will refer newly deployed data.

If you are familiar with SQL profiler, you can set up a trace to watch the commands that SQL Server Agent sends to SQL Server.